# Trouble with templates and __LINE__

Tags: c++, visual-c++, templates, types, standards

I'm working on some code I would like to integrated in a library. I would like it to have no outside dependencies and be standards compliant. I want to use a template to create a unique type to allow compile time type checking.

**Update:**
The code below is from msdn, it is not what I try to do. What I try to do is use a template to have a unique type everytime the user instantiates it using a macro. This way one can do compile time checking that the types don't mix. Im working on the code from this article: http://www.artima.com/cppsource/safelabels.html and yes, I'm aware of the existence of std::bitset thank you.

As Tony pointed out, `__LINE__` isn't a strong guarantee for uniqueness anyway.

I run into the following error:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyf0z2ka%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

```
C2975 will also occur when you use `__LINE__` as a compile-time constant with /ZI:

// C2975b.cpp
// compile with: /ZI
// processor: x86
template<long line> 
void test(void) {}

int main() {
    test<__LINE__>();   // C2975
    test<__LINE__>();   // OK
}
```

Compiling without /ZI is all good, but it is default in msvc and I don't envision having all users of my library first running into compiler errors until I tell them to turn of that switch.

How would you tackle this problem?

The only realistic idea I have so far is checking for the presence of msvc and then use `__COUNTER__` for msvc...

update:
Actually `__COUNTER__` does not work, because I need types to be unique at each declaration, but for different translation units they have to be the same, otherwise I get linker trouble of unresolved external references.

Comment: erm... that's not a template like I have ever seen it done `template<class T> 
void test(void) {}` would be the standard way I know off

Comment: If you just want a unique value, how about using `__COUNTER__` on MSVC, and `__LINE__` on everything else? Does `__COUNTER__` trigger the same warning?

Comment: @thecoshman A template need not necessarily take a typename. @Steve, see the last line of my question... counter does compile.

Comment: I think Boost might have some functionality tucked away somewhere for generating unique types like this. Might be worth taking a look.

Comment: @ufotds: sorry, didn't realise that you'd tried it, and got a bit confused whether you did just want the unique value. Sounds as though `__LINE__` (non-conformingly) isn't a compile-time constant with `/ZI`. I'd certainly tackle it by using the workaround, rather than by telling my clients to use a conforming compiler^W^W^W `/Zi`.

Comment: @GMan I already peered at the boost preprocessor library and it hurt my eyes... Sorry if I'm being to harsh to people who suggest boost... I was to fast there. I will remove the earlier comment.

Comment: How would this handle people using the template from the same line in different files?  Doesn't seem much point finding out how to work around this strange VC++ quirk if you still get a broken solution....

Comment: @Tony I figured that. The best idea I have now is to use `__COUNTER__` whenever it is available and only resort to `__LINE__` if it isn't, but I hope someone can come along with a better solution.

Comment: @ufotds: maybe add a const char* template argument and pass in `__FILE__` too?

Comment: @Tony well, this is compile time, so it is restricted to one compilation unit. I doubt the realistic chance that you get two identical line numbers from different files collide is worth the hassle. Further, it is meant to prevent misuse, so you'd have to be so unlucky to add that too, and as soon as some code changes and you have a different line number it stops compiling, and you get another chance to fix the bug. Am I taking it easy, or should that suffice?

Comment: @ufotds: it depends, for example: if you're trying to create distinct types so that some static data is independent, you may find things compile but the separate uses are interacting at run-time.  If you're trying to increase type safety, then it's unlikely you'll accidentally pass a type from a completely different area of the program, and your scheme may be sufficient.  Ultimately, whether your idea's sufficient depends on the scale and professionalism needed of the project, whether/how bugs affect clients etc..

Comment: @ufodts: Note that while `__COUNTER__` works with VC and GCC >= 4.3, it starts with `0` in every translation unit.

Comment: @Tony: You can't pass string literals as template arguments, see e.g. [here](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/techtalk/templates/#stringliteral).

Comment: @Georg: solid point... I can't see any clean way to apply the usual indirection :-(.

Comment: @Georg I had to sleep over it, because at 5 o'clock this morning my brains just seized to function. Actually, it is only a compile time check, so every translation unit wanting to include a type needs to include the headers in which it is declared, and thereby making each instantiation unique for that translation unit. That is enough.

Answer (score 3):

The first challenge to get unique instantiations is to differentiate between translation units. Luckily, this bit is easy:

```
namespace { struct unique_type {}; }
template<typename T> int foo() { return 42; }
static int bar = foo<unique_type>();
```

This can be put in a header, and will instantiate a different `foo<unique_type>()` in every Translation Unit. Adding the `__LINE__` takes a bit of work due to the MSVC bug:

```
namespace {
    struct unique_type{};
    const int LINE = __LINE__;
}
template<typename T, int N> int foo() { return 42; }
static int bar = foo<unique_type, LINE>();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. The anonymous namespace trick is quite cool. I'm glad to learn about this. However I don't entirely understand what goes on. You seem to create a unique function? The type of bar will always just be int right? What I try to do is compile time checking, so in fact as far as I understand it a type to be unique in one translation unit. I want to prevent users to use operators and assignment of something that is basically an int, but has a different semantic meaning and should not be mixed. So I want to pass something unique as parameter of a template so I get a unique type.

Comment: It turns out `__LINE__` is probably not the best thing anyway, because if people declare something in different headers on the same line or in the same file on the same line, that is not unique. I currently have a macro which hides all this from the end user. They just specify the name of their type and can then rest easy that it won't get mixed with others declared elsewhere.

Comment: just using `__COUNTER__` works but is not standard compliant and not supported by all compilers

Comment: @ufotds: Yes, the bar is just a dummy definition so I can show the instantiations of `foo<unique_type>`. Each translation unit (.cpp plus its headers) has its own anonymous namespace, therefore its own `unique_type`, and therefore also its own `foo<unique_type>`.